# mod_rewrite N number of directories before URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect users from a URL formatted like this:

```
http://blog.mysite.com/any/number/of/directories/<POSTNAME>.html
```

TO:

```
http://mysite.com/about/blog/entry/<POSTNAME>/
```

Where  is the same hyphen-separated string, and, the original URL can have any number of directories before the filename (none of which are 'passed' to the new URL).

Is it possible to create a htaccess rule which reaads this pattern?

Many thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ http://example.com/about/blog/entry/$1/ [R=301,L]
```